# How to fetch the attachment value in RsForm=

Tags: php, forms, joomla, file-handling

I am using RsForm pro on Joomla 3.5. I am working on a form where I submit the data to an API.

RsForm has it's own syntax for posting data. For example:
If I have a text field called requester, I post data using following syntax:

```
$_POST['form']['requester']
```

For a drop-down with time values, its:

```
$_POST['form']['time']['0']
```

Similarly, I need to post an attachment. But I do not find the syntax to do so on RsForm documentation nor am I able to post a question there since my colleague who owns the credentials to login to RsForm site is on holiday. Hence I post the question here.

Also, it looks like after upload the file is renamed. I would like to add a piece of PHP code which can rename the file and I can store the file name in a variable which I can use in the call to the API.

Any help here would be appreciated, since I need to finish the form as soon as possible.

Thanks,
Pooja

Comment: Thats a paid component. You can get help for those components which are free as that can be downloaded and checked by us. Also if you can share the codes that can help us.

Comment: Hi Amit,thanks for the response. Yes, its a paid component. This is what I am trying to do 
$url = 'http://xxxxxx/sdpapi/request/'.$ticket.'/attachment?OPERATION_NAME=ADD_ATTACHMENT&TECHNICIAN_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$path = 'components/com_rsform/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $path . $_POST['form']['attachment'] ;
$post = array('file_contents'=>'@'.$uploadfile);  and post using curl.

Comment: But I am unsure if $uploadfile = $path . $_POST['form']['attachment'] ; is correct, also the file is getting renamed when its uploaded to components/com_rsform/uploads/. so not sure if I have to handle that first and then upload it.

Comment: thanks Amit, email sent.

Comment: Thanks. I will go through that and get back to you soon.

Comment: Perfect, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a complete research on this I came up with the following

While creating an attachment you will get an Attributes Tab. To generate a prefix dynamically you can specify the code in between the `//<code>` and `//</code>`
For example

```
//<code>
return $_POST['form']['name_field'];
//</code>
```

Check this snapshot
[image]

If you want to keep the same file name without any prefix than simply do this

```
//<code>
return '';
//</code>
```

These files can than be easily linked the way you have said in the comments. For more details you can check this link https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/form-fields/file-upload.html

EDIT:

To get the absolute path to your attachments you can use this

```
$path = JPATH_BASE .'/components/com_rsform/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $path . $_POST['form']['attachment'] ;
```

Comment: Thanks Amit I will give a try and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Hi Amit, the file rename works perfectly. however the code to attach file is not. could you please validate.

Comment: $url = 'http://xxx/sdpapi/request/'.$ticket.'/attachment?OPERATION_NAME=ADD_ATTACHMENT&TECHNICIAN_KEY=xxx';
$path = JPATH_BASE .'components/com_rsform/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $path . $_POST['form']['attachment'] ;
$post = array('file_contents'=>'@'.$uploadfile);
 
    $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 $result=curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);

Comment: You have used `$path = JPATH_BASE .'components/com_rsform/uploads/';` it should be `$path = JPATH_BASE .'/components/com_rsform/uploads/'; ` You have to put a front slash before components.

Comment: Yeah, I did try that first it didnt work so tried without slash. Neither of it is working strangely.

Comment: Did you do a var_dump of all the variables and checked what output you are getting. You can do var_dump($path); var_dump($_POST['form']['attachment']); exit; Post the output here.

Comment: "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\insight-devtest/components/com_rsform/uploads/"        NULL string(65) no wonder it was not posting. does it give you any clue how the slashes can be handled (I tried changing the slashes to back slashes but didnt help) and why we get a NULL string? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, if I print the $ticket  its like - NULL string(65) "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\insight-devtest/components/com_rsform/uploads/" string(6) "291961" . I just need the ticket number and need to strip off the string(6) and the double quotes.

Comment: Thats ok in var_dump you get output like this but when you use it in your url it will just be without string(6) and double quotes. Your $_POST['form']['attachment'] value is probably null. Where have you used this code. I mean which component or plugin or module etc,..

Comment: Oh Okay, I have used it in the "Script called after form has been processed" section of the Rsform. The attachment field name in the form is attachment.

Comment: I managed to get the filename from the database by doing this                        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery();
$attach = $db->q($_POST['form']['attachment']);
$db->setQuery("SELECT FieldValue from icnab_rsform_submission_values where FormId = 84 AND `FieldValue`=".$db->quote($_POST['form']['attachment']));
$db->execute();
$file = $db->loadResult();  which outputs - [file_contents] => @D:\inetpub\wwwroot\insight-devtest\components\com_rsform\uploads\905849_persons.xml, which is what I expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, the API is unable to upload.Operation completed without any errors(curl) but FailedError when performing - ADD_ATTACHMENT - null from API. But Thanks anyways for all your help! Appreciate it.

Comment: @PoojaAmbre  Sorry due to weekend engagements I was unable to look into the issue. I will check again and get back to you soon.